# How to send payload with web-push-csharp

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'd like to make web push with c#. In the backend I use [web-push-csharp](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp). I try to test it with postman before pass the API to frontend developer but I get this error.

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
> "ExceptionMessage": "The best overloaded method match for 'WebPush.WebPushClient.SendNotificationAsync(WebPush.PushSubscription, string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>)' has some invalid arguments",
> "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException",

The error comes from payload in the json body because when I replace it with a simple string , the error is gone.

This is the json body in postman:

```
{
"pushEndpoint": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dcgmkACMNNA:APA9*********AJnVo_-qeIOoW1iL36Xh0mpmD4",
"p256dh": "BDFpcRgYyCGLuKwOC6hX*********5a3dBTeWQ",
"auth" : "XAH********GdiSFA",
"subject": "test push",
"publicKey": "BNeGd1***********1ufa8",
"privateKey": "Ce1h**********SOE",
"payload": {
    "notification": {
    "title": "Notifications are cool",
    "body": "Know how to send notifications through Angular with this article!",
    "icon": "https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2015/10/02/110808_blog_512x512.png",
    "vibrate":"[100, 50, 100]",
     "data": {
          "url": "https://medium.com/@arjenbrandenburgh/angulars-pwa-swpush-and-swupdate-15a7e5c154ac"
         }
     }
   }
}
```

This is the code:

```
    [Route("api/Notifications/web-push")]
    [HttpPost] 
    public IHttpActionResult webPush([FromBody] PushBody obj)
    {

        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj.payload);
    
        var subscription = new PushSubscription(obj.pushEndpoint, obj.p256dh, obj.auth);
        var vapidDetails = new VapidDetails(obj.subject, obj.publicKey, obj.privateKey);

        var webPushClient = new WebPushClient();
        try
        {
            webPushClient.SendNotificationAsync(subscription, obj.payload, vapidDetails);
        }
        catch (WebPushException exception)
        {
            return Json(new { message = "Http STATUS code" + exception.StatusCode });
        }


        return Json(new { message = "ok" });

    }

public class PushBody
{
    public string pushEndpoint { get; set; }
    public string p256dh { get; set; }
    public string auth { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string publicKey { get; set; }
    public string privateKey { get; set; }
    public dynamic payload { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** by creating the payload like this :

```
        var payload = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            notification = new
            {
                title = obj.payload.title,
                body = obj.payload.body,
                icon = obj.payload.icon,
                vibrate = obj.payload.vibrate,
            }
        });
```